# jQuery on click div with 100% screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery to create an overlay div when i click on #Thumb as follows:

```
$('#Thumb').click( function() { 
     $('body').append('<div id="overlayFrame" onclick="unloadPhoto()" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); z-index:100;"></div>');
});
```

Problem is: the 100% height only works for the visible area, all the areas that I have to scroll to are not covered by the div.

Any ideas how I can get the div to be 100% of the entire page not dependent on screen resolution?

Thanks

Comment: use position fixed, that way it just stays in the same place during scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fixed positioning.

```
$('#Thumb').click( function() { 
     $('body').append('<div id="overlayFrame" onclick="unloadPhoto()" style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;right:0;bottom:0;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); z-index:100;"></div>');
});
```

Note the addition of `right:0` and `bottom:0` to stretch the overlay to the size of the viewport.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e2VrL/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of your div equal to the height of the document with `$( document ).height()`
as `height:'+$( document ).height()+'px;`

Try:

```
$('#Thumb').click( function() { 
     $('body').append('<div id="overlayFrame" onclick="unloadPhoto()" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:'+$( document ).height()+'px;top:0px;left:0px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); z-index:100;"></div>');
});//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ ADD THIS
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w3Dng/)

+1  Patrick Evans you can just change the position from `absolute` to `fixed` like this:

```
 $('#Thumb').click( function() { 
     $('body').append('<div id="overlayFrame" onclick="unloadPhoto()" style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); z-index:100;"></div>');
});
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/w3Dng/2/)